# Cypress intercept match not matching a single word

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I have read the docs on Cypress `v6.9.1` about [intercept](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept) but I'm having some difficulties truly understanding how to match single words urls.

A practical example of a problem I'm facing. I'm making the following request to create a `label` in my app:

```
POST http://localhost:8081/70e70322-1633-4ca9-b1e2-9240cef416e7/label
```

I would assume, from the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Matching-method) that I could match this route just by doing:

```js
// My code
cy.intercept("POST", "/label").as("createLabel");

// From the examples in Cypress pages
cy.intercept('GET', '/users')
// matches this: GET http://localhost/users
// ...but not this: POST http://localhost/users
```

I have tried the following approaches:

```js
// Passing a simple string
cy.intercept("POST", "label").as("createLabel");

// Passing a regex
cy.intercept("POST", /label/g).as("createLabel");

// Passing a glob pattern
cy.intercept("POST", "**/label").as("createLabel");
```

I'm scratching my head with this one and not truly understanding what exactly is the way to intercept a request based on a single word. This is a simple example but I have faced this problem in many other tests where, to solve my problem I had to intercept all requests (which makes my tests brittle and not future proof):

```js
// This is just a "hacky" way to make it work and avoid the app to 
// make a request to my backend after creating another resource
cy.intercept("GET", "*");
```

## Question

How can I make Cypress match a single word in a request?

- `GET http://localhost/label` -> please, intercept the requests that has `label` on the URL
- `POST http://localhost/user/{userId}/comment` -> please, intercept the requests that has `user` on them
- `POST http://localhost/user/{userId}/comment` -> please, intercept the requests that has `comment` on them

Comment: Did you check cy.intercept('GET', '**/label') and it is not working for you? Maybe you could use Cypress.minimatch to find a suitable pattern more easily --> https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/minimatch

Comment: @SebastianoVierk It is quite useful for testing. I tried your solution as well but not matching. I didn't exactly found what is the problem and went with the solution of matching a more restricted way with `cy.intercept("GET", "label?page=1")`. This seems to solve my issue for now. If an answer is found I will write an answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Sebastiano I used [minimatch](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/minimatch#Usage) and discovered that when I don't add the options it doesn't match.

An example:

```js
// doesnt match
cy.intercept("POST", "**/label").as("createLabel");

// it maches
cy.intercept("POST", "**/label", { statusCode: 200 }).as("createLabel");
```

Comment: Nice that you found a solution, yet strange that options have to be passed for it to work

Comment: `{ statusCode: 200 }` is a StaticResponse, not "options".  The difference between the two commands above is that the 2nd does not go out to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('cy.intercept', () => {

    it('http://localhost/label', () => {
        cy.intercept('**/label').as('alias1');
    });

    it('http://localhost/user/{userId}/comment', () => {
        cy.intercept({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '**/user/*',
        }).as('alias2');
    });

    it('http://localhost/user/{userId}/comment', () => {
        cy.intercept({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '**/comment',
        }).as('alias3');
    });


    it('other try', () => {
        cy.intercept({
            method: 'POST',
            hostname: 'localhost',
            path: '**/comment', //pathname: will also work
        }).as('alias4');
    });
});
```

`alias1` is without curly braces as GET is default method.

**hostname** - means api hostname part (https://example.com)

**url** - means whole api address with endpoint and queries (no queries in these cases)

**path** - HTTP path after hostname, with queries

**pathname** - like path, but without query

Read up here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.